# Opening someone's LinkedIn profile in private browser session tracks visit back to me

Tags: linkedin

I was logged in to LinkedIn, and saw a colleague's name as a link on a page.

I copied the profile link, opened another browser (in Private/Incognito mode), and visited the profile. (This is the first time I ever visited this profile.)

The next time I logged in, it showed the profile in question in the "You recently visited" section.

This is the 3rd/4th time this happened.

How is this possible?

Comment: [Disclaimer: this is pure speculation.] Could be that the respective link wasn’t just a simple direct link to the respective profile, but a redirect one (à la Twitter’s t.co redirects). Or, even if it was direct, it had some unique parameters attached to it.

Comment: I searched for a profile on google > right click > copy link. The link was a google redirect, with the query's url parameter="in.linkedin.com/in/[profile]"

Answer (score 1):

1. It was a redirect link (something like Twitter's t.co)
2. The Link was with attached parameters and a particular parameter has your linkedIn id or a code corresponding to your linkedIn id in it.
3. You were logged into LinkedIn from the Incognito mode, or it really wasn't incognito mode.
4. You were tracked by means of a cookie or may be linked in even does ip tracking.